# Deleting rows from phpMyAdmin doesn't work sometimes

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Using the UI delete button from the phpMyAdmin util when testing something, doesn't seem to work half of the time. I click delete, the page refreshes, nothing is deleted. I checked if the row was deleted by running a manual query and it's still there.

Once I close and reopen phpMyAdmin it works again.

Seems like a bug, but still, can I do anything about it?, I've heard somewhere that it happens because I have no unique fields or primary keys, which I don't since there are no unique fields in this table.

Comment: If you really don't have a unique column, a message is displayed at the top of the screen and the edit and delete buttons are hidden. You're looking in the Browse tab, correct? Anyway, having or not having a unique field should have no effect on how the data is displayed -- each time phpMyAdmin loads the Browse page the results are fetched directly from the database; I can't think of any reason phpMyAdmin would exhibit this behavior, it's very strange. What phpMyAdmin version do you have?

Comment: The delete buttons do show, and yes I'm using the delete in the browse panel. The version is 3.5.1 should I update to the latest?.

Comment: I do suggest upgrading because 3.5.1 is rather outdated at this point. I can't test with 3.5 because it's that old, but know that version 4 will warn you if there aren't unique fields or primary keys (which are needed to make sure the proper data gets deleted). I'm not sure that's the problem, because closing and reopening shouldn't affect that, but I've seen stranger things. Please do try upgrading and letting us know if it helps.

Answer (score -1):

You should add a unique field, as primary keys are necessary to index your table, allowing *much* faster queries. If this doesn't fix your problem, you should either

1. Manually delete the data
2. Look at [SQL Buddy](http://sqlbuddy.com), or other alternatives.